# Primefaces call p:ConfirmDialog by javaScript

Tags: javascript, primefaces, confirm

I would like to call p:confirmDialog by JavaScript , but it come empty:

I need put message text, header text and command in button by Js. Any one can help me

My code in Js:

```
function callConfirm() {
            if(document.getElementById('formPrincipal:valorComanda').value == '0,00'){ 
                PF('confirm').show(); 
            }
}
```

This is my confirm in html:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip"
                widgetVar="confirm">
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
                    icon="ui-icon-check" />
                <p:commandButton value="No" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
                    icon="ui-icon-close" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
```

the call in button:

```
<p:commandButton value="teste" icon="ui-icon-trash"                                             onclick="callConfirm()" update=":formPrincipal,:formMenu:grow"/>
```

Comment: it depends what you want to do, when should it be called? you can add this to the onclick attribute of your commandButton:   onclick="verificaSeComandaZerada(); callConfirm();"

Comment: There is a p:imputText if his value == 0 so I call confirmt.`if(document.getElementById('formPrincipal:valorComanda').value == '0,00'){
     
     PF('confirm').show();
    }`

Comment: Update your question with that inputtext, im guessing you should call it on an onkeydown or onchange event of your inputtext but lets see